# Would like a user to be able to determine which URLs a chrome extension's css / js is applied to

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I am working on that adds CSS / JS to a specific website. The CSS / JS is being applied to the site via the content_scripts section.

I set the "matches" property in the manifest.json file to match any URL from the site, however I'd like my users to be able to stop the extension from being applied to any page of the website they'd like.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess You should provide the option page, so that user can change preferences.
In order to preserve user's setting, you can use local storage or local storage API that Chrome provides.

Option Page

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html

Chrome Storage

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html